# How to resolve Xcode codesign error about multiple binaries sharing the same path?

Tags: xcode

When I try to export a signed copy of my application from the Archives screen, I get the following error.

I used `find . -type l ls` to find symlinks in my project directory: there are none. I went to the `Xcode/Archives` folder for this archive and searched for symlinks there, and there are some but none of them are in the DevMateKit.framework mentioned in the error message. I've also tried adding a build step to manually delete the second binary, but it doesn't help.

The code signing is being done automatically by Xcode, and the files are being copied through a standard Copy Files task. There is also one manual piece of code signing, done through a Run Script task, which manually codesigns a different framework to the one in the error message (although I can't see how that would be relevant). My Xcode version is 6.3.1.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I believe this was an issue with the DevMateKit.framework, and it appears to be fixed in version 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DevMateKit v1.1.1 or less, check your '*Link Binary With Libraries*' build phase and phase where you are copying frameworks and remove *DevMateIssuesReporter.framework* from the list if it's present there. If it won't help, just contact DevMate support with this problem or create a new issue with GitHub (https://github.com/DevMate/DevMateKit)

Comment: `DevMateIssuesReporter.framework` isn't in the _Link Binary With Libraries_ build phase. Only `DevMateKit.framework` is.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I *believe* the reason this happens is as follows. The `DevMateKit.framework` is pre-codesigned by the developer. But I suspect that their source has symlinks in it, and they have signed it all in such a way that this error occurs, but when packaging the framework for download have removed the symlinks so it appears there is nothing that code be done.

I experimented with signing the code myself, which I think would work, but after some experimentation decided to simply delete the binaries that are directly inside any `CrashReporter.framework` directory, and leave the ones inside any `CrashReporter.framework/Versions/.../` directory. This removes the duplicated binaries and appears to work perfectly.

But I'm not an expert on this process, so it's entirely possible that I was just doing something wrong.